# Disabled button still fires using ".click()"

Tags: javascript, jquery

It seems **disabled button** "onclick" function is still fired when triggering it programmaticaly, eg:

```
<div>
   <input type="button" onclick="save()" id="saveButton"    value="save"  disabled="disabled" />
   <input type="button" onclick="byPassDisabled()" value="bypass disabled button"/>
<div id="counter">0</div>
```

```
function save(){
    var count = parseInt($('#counter').html());
    $('#counter').html(++count);
}
function byPassDisabled(){
     $('#saveButton').click();   
}
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/WzEvs/363/

In my situation, keyboards shortcuts are bound to functions triggering the ".click()" on buttons. I'll find it very annoying to have to disable the shorcuts or check if the button is disabled myself. I'd prefer a general solution fixing this problem.

- But why? This behavior doesn't seem fair to me.
- Any workaround?

Comment: thanks for the valuable input. I just believe this is not an expected behavior, that's all.
Alternatively, I may use $('#saveButton:enabled').click(); instead.

Comment: First, do not use inline handlers. Your buttons have ids. Use jquery to bind event handlers `$('#id').click(blah)`. Second, do not simulate events to trigger another functionality. `function tryToSave() {if(currentStateAllowYouToSave) save();}`.

Comment: 1. I'm using angular ng-click to bind the save function, I cannot use id to bind it.
2. Keyboards shortcuts are ment to trigger buttons.
3. I do not want to have to check the button state, it's an hassle

Comment: well, there are no angular library to handle keyboard shortcuts, are there?

Comment: http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular-hotkeys

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The attribute only disables user interaction, the button is still usable programmatically.

So yeah, you gotta check

```
function byPassDisabled(){
    $('#saveButton:enabled').click();   
}
```

Alternatively don't use inline handlers.

```
$(document).on('click', '#saveButton:enabled', function(){
    // ...
});
```

Comment: :not(:disabled) can be shortened to :enabled

Comment: Yeah, thanks. Was too focused on the disabled check :D

Comment: Actually, I use angular ng-click.

Comment: "clicking" is **not** user interaction?

Answer (score 5):

For future use...the OP code works because jQuery will still call it's own handlers even if the DOM element is disabled. If one were to use vanilla javascript, the disabled attribute would be honored.

```
const element = document.getElementById('saveButton');
element.click() //this would not work
```

Comment: This is correct, thanks for posting this. I ran into a similar issue while using React and was confused by the number of jQuery-related posts which stated that my disabled button is still active when .click() is used, despite the fact that I was doing just that in my code and a disabled button was not firing.

Comment: I noticed `element.dispatchEvent(new Event("click"))` would still work

Answer (score 2):

> You can programmatically trigger click on a disabled button.

There are ways to find if the event is a click on button by user or it has been trigger programmatically. http://jsfiddle.net/WzEvs/373/

```
$(function () {
    $("#saveButton").on('click', function (e) {
        if (!e.isTrigger) {
            var count = parseInt($('#counter').html());
            $('#counter').html(++count);
        }
    });
    $("#bypassButton").on('click', function (e) {
        $("#saveButton").click();
    });
});
```

`e.isTrigger` is true if you call the `click()` programmatically. Basically you are triggering the click event manually in code.

Comment: Spokey's solution is way simpler.

Comment: I agree, but this might fit at requirements where we want to identify if it is a user click or triggered one :)

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger `click` still although made it `disable` .As Spokey said it just shows the user-interaction(the usability still persists that can be turned on programmatically) . 
`off` or `unbind` the click will solve this issue.

Thanks