# Prevent button from being clicked programmatically

Tags: javascript, button

I have the following button:

```
<input type="button" disabled onClick=document.location.href="?hash=blabla" tabindex="-1" class="btn btn-transparent btn-xs cbut0" />
```

Now the button is disabled and using another script to re-enable it on mouse-over event, however it seems users can still click the button programmatically by loading a simple external javascript such as:

```
window.onload = setTimeout(function(){
$('input.btn.btn-transparent').click();
}, 10000);
```

Is there any way to prevent this behavior, somehow making sure the button is clicked on by a mouse and not by some script?

I found some leads at [Disabled button still fires using ".click()"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28213070/disabled-button-still-fires-using-click) but failed to implement it in my case.

Comment: Why? If they're going to the effort of clicking it programmatically, there's nothing stopping them from just running `document.location.href="?hash=blablah"` themselves.

Comment: For context - what's the motivation? Why are you worried about arbitrary scripts clicking on the button? Is this a security issue somehow, or is it a usability issue? Or just curiosity/for learning?

Comment: The hash value is random on each load so they can't trigger that automatically. The motivation here is to prevent automatic scripts on clicking the button.

Comment: It is really impossible. They can just read the link.

Comment: please dont prevent automatic scripts from clicking the button :( sites that do that are a pain. a better alternative: throttle requests to prevent abusive botting

Comment: Throttling requests won't stop abusers from clicking the button once it's visible unfortunately.

Comment: Let me put it this way. If I *really* wanted to run this code, I could just do `eval(document.querySelector('selector.to.get.button').onclick)`. You can't stop someone from doing that. You have to solve the problem on the server-side. The client can *always* be manipulated.

Comment: @Ivan check my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42423007/3543808)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can make use of `isTrusted` property of `event`.
Have a look at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted).

> The isTrusted read-only property of the Event interface is a boolean that is true when the event was generated by a user action, and false when the event was created or modified by a script or dispatched via dispatchEvent.

## Demo

```js
function changeHash(event) {
  if (event.isTrusted) {
    alert("Trusted");
  } else {
    alert("Programmatically triggered");
  }
}

function triggerClick() {
  document.getElementById('btn').click();
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="btn" onClick="changeHash(event)" tabindex="-1" class="btn btn-transparent btn-xs cbut0" value="change">

<button onclick="triggerClick()">Trigger click</button>
```

Below is the sample code to check whether the event is trusted event.

```
if ('isTrusted' in event) {
  if (event.isTrusted) {
    alert('The ' + event.type + ' event is trusted.');
  } else {
    alert('The ' + event.type + ' event is not trusted.');
  }
} else {
  alert('The isTrusted property is not supported by your browser');
}
```

So with this code you can change your code like below to get it working.

### HTML

```
<input type="button" disabled onClick = "changeHash()" tabindex="-1" class="btn btn-transparent btn-xs cbut0" />
```

### JS

```
changeHash(event) {
  if (event.isTrusted) {
    document.location.href = "?hash=blabla"
  } else {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

### Workaround for `event.isTrusted` is to check for `eventX` and `eventY` properties as shown below

```
changeHash(event) {
  if (event.screenX && event.screenY && event.screenX != 0 && event.screenY != 0) {
    document.location.href = '?hash=blabla';
  } else {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm applying this right now. Feeling positive :) Will feedback in a minute.

Comment: Unfortunately it won't work. Getting the following error at the console when clicking on the button: Uncaught ReferenceError: changeHash is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick

Comment: Ah, I was placing it in the header.... As soon as I move it to the body, where it should have been, it worked flawlessly. Thanks alot, much appreciate it!

Comment: You can place it anywhere if you wrap your js code in `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
// Your code goes here
});`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="button"  onmousedown="mouseDown()" value="click me" id="btn">
    <input type="button" value="Btn2" id="btn2">
  <p id="prevented"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
function mouseDown() {
    alert("MD");
}
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#btn").click(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    //prevented click at time:
    $("#prevented").text(new Date());
});

$("#btn2").click(function() {
  $("#btn").click();
});
});
```