# How to make one NOT be able to simulate a click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've noticed while working for someone on a script that this special button ( the login one ): https://www.easports.com/fifa/ultimate-team/web-app/ does not allow to simulate a click on it in any possible way.

I'm extremely curious to know how they do it.
I've tried

```
var btn=$('#Login > div > div > button.btn-standard.call-to-action');
btn.click(); // or trigger('click');

// or
click = new Event(click);
btn.dispatchEvent(click);

// or

btn.trigger('mousedown');

// oh and also:

function click(x, y)
{
 var ev = new MouseEvent('click', {
     'view': window,
     'bubbles': true,
     'cancelable': true,
     'screenX': x,
     'screenY': y
 });

 var el = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);

 el.dispatchEvent(ev);
}
```

I've even tried mouseenter, followed by mousedown and mouseup;

How can one achieve this sort of feature?

Comment: F12 dev tools in Google should let you view their code using the Network tab if "view source" isn't working for you.

Comment: if is it LOGIN button it does not have disabled class so your selector is wrong

Comment: $('#Login > div > div > button.btn-standard.call-to-action.disabled').length is 0, without .disabled is 1

Comment: that was a mistake on my part, I never used the disabled selector. code updated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent button from being clicked programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42422888/prevent-button-from-being-clicked-programatically)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of what they might be doing. `Event.isTrusted` gives you information on if it was a user action or a created event. They probably have some logic around this:

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted):

> The isTrusted read-only property of the Event interface is a Boolean
>   that is true when the event was generated by a user action, and false
>   when the event was created or modified by a script or dispatched via
>   EventTarget.dispatchEvent().

```js
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', (e) => console.log(e.isTrusted));

// Simulate a click onload (should print false to the console)
document.getElementById('btn').click(); // false

// TODO: Click the Button manually, you should see 'true' being printed
```

```html
<button id="btn">Button</button>
```

My guess is that if you look into their source code, you'd see something similar where they are just doing an `.stopPropogation` or `.preventDefault` if `isTrusted` is false.

So they are probably doing this:

```js
document.getElementById('btn1').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (!e.isTrusted) { e.preventDefault(); return;}
  console.log('Button clicked!');

});

document.getElementById('btn1').click(); // nothing printed to console.
```

```html
<button id="btn1">Button</button>
```

Comment: I believe they use something more complex, I've read that you can fake these as well via debugger. in their code there is something like ``` if (_0x51d7b6 instanceof MouseEvent) { ``` I couldn't find anything related to isTrusted

Comment: I'm sure it's a little more elegant, but more than likely, very similar.